# Sign in as a different user using MVC.NET and Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

How can I accomplish this using MVC.NET?  I've found resources on the Internet about how to do it in ASP.NET, but I haven't found a way to do it in MVC.NET (I'm an MVC.NET newbie, though).  I can generate a 401 response using [Authorize] attributes but I don't have any idea about what to do after that.

[EDIT]
After some playing around, I figured that if I can find a way to force the application to reauthenticate itself and bring up the login dialog, I may be able to do this.  I think that if I set the Authorization attribute to something like [Authorize(Users="NooneAllowed")] it should bring up the login dialog.  Is there another way to force it to reauthenticate, because the above hack is pretty much useless as it will still deny access.

Comment: Logically not much should have changed within MVC or any other framework that uses the standard Authentication model (from ASP.NET). Are you sure you are not suffering from cache/cookie issues?

Comment: If you programatically log out (`SignOut`) the current user, the next request for an action that requires authentication will require the user to log in again. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have to asign role for each user on time of registration by using the below code

```
Roles.CreateRole(RoleName);
Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, RoleName);
```

Role name as "Admin" or "User" or "Employee" or "Customer" or what ever you wish it may.
You should done it on the time of registration.

Then you define the like this to differentiate the using for users.
If you need Admin only to take access the below method, then you have to define the role as "Admin"

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult ViewInventoryList()
    {
        List<Inventory> inventoryList = new List<Inventory>();
        inventoryList = connectDatabase.SelectInventory();
        return View("ViewInventory", inventoryList);
    }
```

If you need User only to take access the below method, then you have to define the role as "User"

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult ViewInventoryList()
    {
        List<Inventory> inventoryList = new List<Inventory>();
        inventoryList = connectDatabase.SelectInventory();
        return View("ViewInventory", inventoryList);
    }
```